# Does multiprocessing pool.map run jobs simultaneously?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I went through documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers and
I don't quite understand what "It blocks until the result is ready" means.
Does it mean any of these:

1. For `pool.map(worker_num = 5)`, those 5 workers will work one by one and the result will block until it ready?
2. For `pool_job_1 = pool.map(4);pool_job_2 = pool.map(4).` The `pool_job_2` will only start after `pool_job_1` finished?

I am favor of second explanation right now. This is important to what I am doing, since I want to run it by order and only one at a time. How can I achieve that? I can using lock and pass it into Process as argument:

```
for item in my_list:
    Process(func, (item,lock...))
```

And in my function, I add `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` to make sure it will run one process at a time. The problem with this method is: I will create too many processes (`processes = length of my_list`).

I am thinking adding lock in map function or set `processes = 1` in pool.

**Update:**

By playing with dummy example, one should have clear idea about what map function is doing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import os
import time

def sleeper(args):
   name = args[0]
   seconds = args[1]
   print ('starting child process with id:%d '% os.getpid())
   print ('parent process:%d' % os.getppid())
   print ('sleeping for %s ' % seconds)
   time.sleep(seconds)
   print ("Done sleeping")


# if __name__ == '__main__':
#    print ("in parent process (id %d)" % os.getpid())
#    for j in reversed(range(10,15)):
#       p = Process(target=sleeper, args=('bob', j))
#       p.start()
#       print ("in parent process after child process start")
#       print ("parent process about to join child process")
#       p.join()
#       print ("in parent process after child process join")
#       print ("parent process exiting with id %d "% os.getpid())
#       print ("The parent's parent process:%d" % os.getppid())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print ("in parent process (id %d)" % os.getpid())
   pool = Pool(1)
   pool.map(sleeper, [('bob',x) for x in reversed(range(10,15))], 1)
```

It starts whatever processes in the beginning, and divide your "iterable" into those processes. But one thing that I missed earlier is: it doesn't create new processes in the middle, instead, it uses processes it created in the beginning all the time.

Comment: If you want to run in order, one at a time, why are you using a pool of workers?  There's overhead associated with parallelizing your code, and it sounds like you're explicitly wanting to run it in serial.

Comment: Explanation 2 is correct. `pool.map()` will block but will execute the mapping using available processes from the pool. If you depend on `pool_job_1` to complete before `pool_job_2`, just following the pattern you described in Explanation 2.

Comment: @JeffL.Hi, Yea actually you are right. It is long story. Basically I am rewriting for loop in one python code using multiprocessing since memory issue. And after I finished that, I realized that for some limitations, I can only run my job one at a time..

Comment: Using pool actually will use more memory than just serial Python as it starts additional Python instances in the background as workers...